# ¿A que se refieren las clases de entidad, control e interfaz?

Tags: java, poo

Hasta dónde he entendido las **clases entidad** son las que sirven para modelar los datos, por ejemplo crear una clase Persona que agrupe todos sus atributos. 
Las **clases de control** son más que se encargan de realizar lo que el usuario desea. 
Las **clases de interfaz** son las que se encargan de las vistas, es decir lo que el usuario ve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Así es, si lo quieres ver de otra manera:
Él modeló, efectivamente es referente a los datos, la vista es todo con lo que tu usuario interactúa y el controlador es una "comunicación" entre tu vista y tú modelo además de servir como un "backend" de tu app.

Comment: Por cierto, este modelo tambien se conoce como MVC ó Model, View, Controller